# Remove the [converter]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

[converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/converter) (> 2000 Questions, 5 Followers) is all over the place. It does not sound useful. As was [the case with [convert]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141963), it should go.

Comment: We probably need to do a clean-up before setting fire to this one. Based on [BalusC's activity](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:157882%20[converter]%20is:answer), I think `[jsf-converter]` should be a tag.

Comment: What is [tag:jsf-converter]? You got a link?

Comment: It's a JSF interface. http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/j2ee101302/jsf_apps/eventvalidate/sf_avc_converters.html I think the `[converter]` tag here can still be 90% burned, but some questions will have to be retagged first.  There are 175 questions with both tags. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf+converter

Answer (score 2):

**I disagree strongly.**

A converter is an integral part of any XAML code, which means it's used heavily in WPF and Silverlight. Of course there will still be a bunch of questions where that tag has been used inappropriately, those will have to be manually cleaned up.

Comment: Sounds like the case for a *non-generic* tag name for converters in the context of XAML.